# How do I find the maximum speed of ethernet in the walls?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am considering buying a 10 gigabit switch for my internal home network but I am not sure if the ethernet cables in the walls can support those speeds.

I currently have 1000mbps speeds in the wall connection so I assume the cables are at least Cat5e - but I need at least Cat6 for 10,000mbps speeds.

I don't have any fancy tools to probe the ports, I think I can pull the port covers off the walls to see what colour the connected wires are - though I am not sure that will be a good indication.

What options do I have to determine the maximum speed of the internal cabling?

Comment: Easiest will be to open the plates and read the labels on the wires.

Comment: Actually, the cable rating is not enough info. Throughput can often *exceed* cable ratings, though error rate slowly gets higher with speed. Poorly terminated connections and long cable runs can drop speed *below* the nominal rating. You might try a peer-to-peer connection between devices, for a rough idea of speed.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. Your 10 GbE interface cannot magically determine whether you have Cat 5E, Cat 6 or whatever and it also cannot detect your connectors and jacks and whatnot. Just try.

Comment: Yes, there are many factors. @DrMoishePippik's list is good.

Comment: if you have at least two devices with a 10Gb NIC then run an iPerf test between them.

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet cables don't have speeds *per se*. They have signal quality criteria they must meet to be considered "in spec" for certain Ethernet standards. You're right that the standard for 10 gigabit Ethernet over twisted pair copper, IEEE 802.3 10GBASE-T, requires Cat 6 to ensure full 10 gigabit operation at up to 55m total cable path length.

The only way to tell if your cable was designed and tested to meet the Cat 6 criteria is to read the printing on the cable jacket and hope the vendor was trustworthy. Otherwise you'd need a very expensive tester or lab full of test equipment to run all the tests to certify that it meets all the signal quality criteria.

It should be pointed out that your equipment might still be able to get 10Gbps performance over shorter runs of lesser-spec cable. It's not guaranteed by the engineering work done by the IEEE, but it might work. It's worth a try.

Comment: You neglect to consider/mention that a bad installation of any cable and/or damage to the cable during installation can degrade that cable's performance capabilities.